# Control positioning of background image/pattern

Tags: highcharts

My end goal is to create an "arearange" chart that uses the sample background image below such that a given value on the y-axis (e.g. 56) is always represented by the same color/position from the image.

As you can see in the fiddle below, I am able to use highcharts to create an "arearange" chart which uses an arbitrary image to fill/shade the area within the range.  However, even though the two charts have different (y-axis) values, the colors are exactly the same; the peak in June on "Chart 1" is the same color as "Chart 2" even though their values are different (301 vs 401).

http://jsfiddle.net/malonso/YwuqD/1/

Code pertaining to the fill color/pattern:

```cpp
    fillColor: {
        pattern: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dezhE.png',
        width: 10,
        height: 300
    }
```

Is it possible to somehow specify that the background image should cover a specific range on the y-axis?

Sample image:

[image]

UPDATE: For some reason the chart background is no longer showing up as a gradient when viewed in a browser other than chrome, so I have attached a screenshot of what the fiddle looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render the charts use this:

```
/*********************************************************
* Generate the example chart
*********************************************************/
```

```cpp
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Chart 1'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'arearange',
        data: testData,
        fillColor: {
            pattern: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dezhE.png',
            width: 10,
            height: 300 + Math.round(testData[0][0] / 100) * 100
        }
    }]

});

var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Chart 2'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'arearange',
        data: testData2,
        fillColor: {
            pattern: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dezhE.png',
            width: 10,
            height: 300 +  Math.round(testData2[0][0] / 100) * 100
        }
    }]

});
```

It adds the Y axis's starting point (Math.round(testData[0][0] / 100) * 100) to the height of the image.

(There is only a minor change to the code you supplied)

[image: charts]

The difference is kinda subtle

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to update position of the image after chart is rendered. Only limit is to know one point (for example 1st pixel on top of pattern should be for value 500). See example: http://jsfiddle.net/YwuqD/9/

First add reference for future update when creating pattern:

```js
this.upgradeGradients = image;
```

Then in load use this:

```js
        load: function() {
            var chart = this,
                image = chart.renderer.upgradeGradients,
                top = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(500), //500 is the top of image - only for example value
                diff = chart.plotTop + top;

            image.attr({y : diff});
        }
```