# How do I add a gradient to the y-axis of a line chart with HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to construct a line chart with gradient indicators along both y-axes.

Here's an example, which brings me about 90% of the way there:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    // ...
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'parts per million',
            style: {
                color: '#444'
            }
        },
        opposite: true,
        lineColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
                [0.5, 'rgb(255, 255, 0)'],
                [1, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'],

                ]
        },
        lineWidth: 15,
        offset: 10
    }, {
        opposite: false,
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'parts per million',
            style: {
                color: '#444'
            }
        },
        lineColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'],
                [0.5, 'rgb(255, 255, 0)'],
                [1, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)']
            ]
        },
        lineWidth: 15,
        offset: 10
    }]
    // ...
```

(See the full example at http://jsfiddle.net/mmwhx/6/)

The remaining 10% involves having precise control over the gradient "stops", such that they correspond to the values along the y-axes (e.g. from 50-100, the bar should be green; from 100-200, the bar should be yellow; from 200 to the end of the axis, the bar should be red). Because I'm not constraining the range of values along the y-axis, it's impossible to determine where the stops should be using the 0-1.0 scale.

If the maximum value of the y-axis is available somehow, I could always calculate the stops. But something tells me there may be a more elegant way of achieving what I want, though I unfortunately haven't stumbled across any examples.

Comment: As I know, there is no perfect solution for that. To get extremes for xAxis, use `chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();` If you will be using  patterns instead, you can try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304476/control-positioning-of-background-image-pattern).